# Как организовать проверку из приложения, включена ли передача данных на телефоне?

Tags: android, java

Добрый день подскажите пожалуйста в каком направлении идти.

Дело в том, что моё приложение использует интернет, а бывают случаи, что в телефоне пользователи намеренно отключают передачу данных. Мне кажется, для начала мне необходимо это проверить, включена ли передача данных или нет, чтобы не было ошибок непредвиденных, но как это сделать не знаю.
ошибка лог

```
06-30 09:22:28.399: D/myLogs(1063): MyService onCreate _ 
06-30 09:22:28.409: D/AndroidRuntime(1063): Shutting down VM
06-30 09:22:28.409: W/dalvikvm(1063): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
06-30 09:22:28.429: E/AndroidRuntime(1063): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-30 09:22:28.429: E/AndroidRuntime(1063): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create service ru.startandroid.develop.p0931servicestop.MyService: java.lang.SecurityException: ConnectivityService: Neither user 10034 nor current process has android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE.
06-30 09:22:28.429: E/AndroidRuntime(1063):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:1955)
06-30 09:22:28.429: E/AndroidRuntime(1063):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2500(ActivityThread.java:117)
06-30 09:22:28.429: E/AndroidRuntime(1063):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:985)
06-30 09:22:28.429: E/AndroidRuntime(1063):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-30 09:22:28.429: E/AndroidRuntime(1063):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
06-30 09:22:28.429: E/AndroidRuntime(1063):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
06-30 09:22:28.429: E/AndroidRuntime(1063):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-30 09:22:28.429: E/AndroidRuntime(1063):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
06-30 09:22:28.429: E/AndroidRuntime(1063):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
06-30 09:22:28.429: E/AndroidRuntime(1063):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
06-30 09:22:28.429: E/AndroidRuntime(1063):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-30 09:22:28.429: E/AndroidRuntime(1063): Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: ConnectivityService: Neither user 10034 nor current process has android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE.
06-30 09:22:28.429: E/AndroidRuntime(1063):     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1322)
06-30 09:22:28.429: E/AndroidRuntime(1063):     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1276)
06-30 09:22:28.429: E/AndroidRuntime(1063):     at android.net.IConnectivityManager$Stub$Proxy.getActiveNetworkInfo(IConnectivityManager.java:345)
06-30 09:22:28.429: E/AndroidRuntime(1063):     at android.net.ConnectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.java:251)
06-30 09:22:28.429: E/AndroidRuntime(1063):     at ru.startandroid.develop.p0931servicestop.MyService.isOnline(MyService.java:85)
06-30 09:22:28.429: E/AndroidRuntime(1063):     at ru.startandroid.develop.p0931servicestop.MyService.onCreate(MyService.java:25)
06-30 09:22:28.429: E/AndroidRuntime(1063):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:1945)
06-30 09:22:28.429: E/AndroidRuntime(1063):     ... 10 more
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

например:

```
 public boolean isOnline() {
            ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            NetworkInfo nInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
            if (nInfo != null && nInfo.isConnected()) {
                return true; // есть соединение
            }
            else {
                return false; // нет соединения
            }

      }
```

вызов примерно так:

```
if (isOnline() == false) {

Context ctx = getBaseContext();
   Toast.makeText(ctx, "Нет соединения с Интернет!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

   finish();
}
```

wifi включить:

```
WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
wifi.setWifiEnabled(true);
```

ЗЫ! AndroidManifest.xml добавить:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

Comment: Да и на перед вопрос, возможно ли принудительное включение и выключение из приложения передачи данных?

Comment: А этот метод исключений не выбрасывает, что-то не получается проверить ошибку выдаёт.

Comment: Не могу понять в чем дело, вызываю метод в сервисе, ошибка вылетает и на эмуляторе и на реальном телефоне

public void onCreate() {
  super.onCreate();
  Log.d(LOG_TAG, "MyService onCreate"+" _ ");
  isOnline() ;
  es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
  someRes = new Object();
 }
Сам метод ниже находится в классе сервиса. Что не так?

Comment: какая ошибка?

Comment: ошибку в вопрос добавил. Может в манифесте надо было permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE поставить?

Comment: Блин, ну точно в манифест разрешение не добавил. Заработал Спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

GSM соединение можно так установить/проверить

```
private void setMobileDataEnabled(Context context, boolean enabled)
            throws ClassNotFoundException, IllegalArgumentException,
            IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException,
            SecurityException, NoSuchMethodException, NoSuchFieldException {

        final ConnectivityManager conman = (ConnectivityManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        Class conmanClass = Class.forName(conman.getClass().getName());
        final Field iConnectivityManagerField = conmanClass
                .getDeclaredField("mService");
        iConnectivityManagerField.setAccessible(true);
        final Object iConnectivityManager = iConnectivityManagerField
                .get(conman);
        final Class iConnectivityManagerClass = Class
                .forName(iConnectivityManager.getClass().getName());
        final Method setMobileDataEnabledMethod = iConnectivityManagerClass
                .getDeclaredMethod("setMobileDataEnabled", Boolean.TYPE);
        setMobileDataEnabledMethod.setAccessible(true);

        setMobileDataEnabledMethod.invoke(iConnectivityManager, enabled);

    }

private boolean getMobileDataEnabled(Context context)
        throws ClassNotFoundException, IllegalArgumentException,
        IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException,
        SecurityException, NoSuchMethodException, NoSuchFieldException {

    final ConnectivityManager conman = (ConnectivityManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    Class conmanClass = Class.forName(conman.getClass().getName());
    final Field iConnectivityManagerField = conmanClass
            .getDeclaredField("mService");
    iConnectivityManagerField.setAccessible(true);
    final Object iConnectivityManager = iConnectivityManagerField
            .get(conman);
    final Class iConnectivityManagerClass = Class
            .forName(iConnectivityManager.getClass().getName());
    final Method getMobileDataEnabledMethod = iConnectivityManagerClass
            .getDeclaredMethod("getMobileDataEnabled");
    getMobileDataEnabledMethod.setAccessible(true);

    return (Boolean) getMobileDataEnabledMethod
            .invoke(iConnectivityManager);

}
```